# Getting a "vector subscript out of range" error when passing a vector into a function: c++

Tags: c++, vector, range, out

I am trying to write a c++ program that assembles MIPS instructions. While debugging, it keeps throwing an error at line 74 of my main:

`myassembler.add(lexed[i].labels[0], lexed[i].name, tokens, i);`

my main is here:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

#include "exceptions.h"
#include "lexer.h"
#include "util.h"
#include "assembler.h"

std::string read_file(const std::string& name) {
  std::ifstream file(name);
  if (!file.is_open()) {
    std::string error = "Could not open file: ";
    error += name;
    throw std::runtime_error(error);
  }
  std::stringstream stream;
  stream << file.rdbuf();
  return std::move(stream.str());
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // Adjusting -- argv[0] is always filename.
  --argc;
  ++argv;

  if (argc == 0) {
    std::cerr << "Need a file" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  assembler myassembler;


  for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
    std::string asmName(argv[i]);

    if (!util::ends_with_subseq(asmName, std::string(".asm"))) {
      std::cerr << "Need a valid file name (that ends in .asm)" << std::endl;
      std::cerr << "(Bad name: " << asmName << ")" << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }

    // 4 is len(".asm")
    auto length = asmName.size() - string_length(".asm");
    std::string baseName(asmName.begin(), asmName.begin() + length);
    std::string objName = baseName + ".obj";
    try {
      auto text = read_file(asmName);
      try {
        auto lexed = lexer::analyze(text);      // Parses the entire file and returns a vector of instructions

        for (int i =0; i < (int)lexed.size(); i++){

            if(lexed[i].labels.size() > 0)      // Checking if there is a label in the current instruction
                std::cout << "label = " << lexed[i].labels[0] << "\n";      // Prints the label

            std::cout<< "instruction name = " << lexed[i].name<< "\n";      // Prints the name of instruction


            std::cout << "tokens = ";
            std::vector<lexer::token> tokens = lexed[i].args;   
            for(int j=0; j < (int)tokens.size(); j++){       // Prints all the tokens of this instruction like $t1, $t2, $t3
                if (tokens[j].type == lexer::token::Integer)
                    std::cout << tokens[j].integer() << " ";
                else
                    std::cout << tokens[j].string() << " ";
            }
            myassembler.add(lexed[i].labels[0], lexed[i].name, tokens, i);
            myassembler.p();
            std::cout << "\n\n\n";
        }

      } catch(const bad_asm& e) {
        std::stringstream error;
        error << "Cannot assemble the assembly code at line " << e.line;
        throw std::runtime_error(error.str());
        } catch(const bad_label& e) {
         std::stringstream error;
        error << "Undefined label " << e.what() << " at line " << e.line;
        throw std::runtime_error(error.str());
        }

    } catch (const std::runtime_error& err) {
      std::cout << err.what() << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }
  }
  /*getchar();*/
  return 0;
}
```

assembler.h:

```
#include "lexer.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct symbol
{
    std::string label = "";
    int slinenum;

};

struct relocation
{
    std::string instruct = "";
    std::string label = "";
    int rlinenum;
    int rt = 0;
    int rs = 0;
};

struct opcode
{
    std::string instruct = "";
    int opc = 0;
    bool isloadstore = false;
    int extType = 0;
    bool isbranch = false;
};

struct function
{
    std::string instruct = "";
    int funct = 0;
    bool isjr = false;
    bool isshift = false;
};

struct regs
{
    std::string name;
    int num;
};

enum instrtype
{
    R, I, neither
};

class assembler
{
public:
    assembler();
    void oinit(void);
    void finit(void);
    void rinit(void);
    void printToFile(std::fstream &file);
    void savesymb(std::string label, int line);
    void saverel(std::string instr, std::string label, int line, int rt, int rs);
    std::vector<int> formatr(std::string instr, lexer::token toke1, lexer::token toke2, lexer::token toke3, int line);
    int formatr(std::string instr, lexer::token toke, int line);
    std::vector<int> formati(std::string instr, lexer::token toke1, lexer::token toke2, lexer::token toke3, int line);
    std::vector<int> formati(std::string instr, lexer::token toke1, lexer::token toke2, int line);
    int findnum(std::string regname);
    void add(std::string label, std::string instr, const std::vector<lexer::token> &tokens, int linen);
    void secAdd(void);
    int rassemble(std::string instr, int rd, int rs, int rt, int shamt);
    int iassemble(std::string instr, int rt, int rs, int imm);
    void p();
private:
    std::vector<int> results;
    std::vector<symbol> symbtable;
    std::vector<relocation> reloctable;
    std::vector<opcode> ops;
    std::vector<function> functions;
    std::vector<regs> registers;
    instrtype type = neither;
};
```

and assembler.cpp:

```
// ECE 2500
// Project 1: myAssembler
// assembler.cpp
// Sheila Zhu

#include "lexer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "assembler.h"

assembler::assembler()
{
    oinit();
    finit();
    rinit();
}

void assembler::oinit()
{
    opcode myop;
    myop.instruct = "addi";
    myop.opc = 8;
    myop.extType = 1;
    ops.push_back(myop);
    // more of the same
}

void assembler::finit()
{
    function myfunc;
    myfunc.instruct = "add";
    myfunc.funct = 32;
    functions.push_back(myfunc);
    // more of the same
}

void assembler::rinit()
{
    regs myreg;
    myreg.name = "$zero";
    myreg.num = 0;
    registers.push_back(myreg);
    //more of the same
}

void assembler::printToFile(std::fstream &file)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)results.size(); i++)
        file << results.at(i) << std::endl;
}

void assembler::savesymb(std::string label, int line)
{
    symbol symb;
    symb.label = label;
    symb.slinenum = line * 4;
    symbtable.push_back(symb);
}

void assembler::saverel(std::string instr, std::string label, int line, int rt, int rs)
{
    relocation re;
    re.instruct = instr;
    re.label = label;
    re.rlinenum = line;
    re.rt = rt;
    re.rs = rs;
}

int assembler::findnum(std::string regname)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)registers.size(); i++)
    {
        if (regname == registers.at(i).name)
            return registers.at(i).num;
    }
    return -1;
}

std::vector<int> assembler::formatr(std::string instr, lexer::token toke1, lexer::token toke2, lexer::token toke3, int line)
{
    int rd = 0, rs = 0, rt = 0, shamt = 0;
    std::vector<int> x;
    function currf;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)functions.size(); i++)
    {
        if (instr == functions.at(i).instruct)
            currf = functions.at(i);
    }
    try
    {
        if (currf.isshift)
        {
            if (toke1.type == lexer::token::Integer)
                throw 1;
            else
            {
                rd = findnum(toke1.string());
                if (rd == -1)
                    throw 2;
            }
            if (toke2.type == lexer::token::Integer)
                throw 1;
            else
            {
                rs = findnum(toke2.string());
                if (rs == -1)
                    throw 2;
            }
            if (toke3.type == lexer::token::Integer)
            {
                shamt = toke3.integer();
                if (shamt < 0)
                    throw 3;
            }
            else
                throw 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (toke1.type == lexer::token::Integer)
                throw 1;
            else
            {
                rd = findnum(toke1.string());
                if (rd == -1)
                    throw 2;
            }
            if (toke2.type == lexer::token::Integer)
                throw 1;
            else
            {
                rs = findnum(toke2.string());
                if (rs == -1)
                    throw 2;
            }
            if (toke3.type == lexer::token::Integer)
                throw 1;
            else
            {
                rt = findnum(toke3.string());
                if (rt == -1)
                    throw 2;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        if (e == 1)
            std::cerr << "Wrong argument in line " << line << std::endl;
        else if (e == 2)
            std::cerr << "Invalid register name in line " << line << std::endl;
        else
            std::cerr << "Shift amount cannot be negative in line " << line << std::endl;
    }
    x.push_back(rd);
    x.push_back(rs);
    x.push_back(rt);
    x.push_back(shamt);
    return x;
}

int assembler::formatr(std::string instr, lexer::token toke, int line)
{
    int rs = 0;
    try
    {
        if (toke.type == lexer::token::Integer)
            throw 1;
        else
        {
            rs = findnum(toke.string());
            if (rs == -1)
                throw 2;
        }
    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        if (e == 1)
            std::cerr << "Wrong argument in line " << line << std::endl;
        else
            std::cerr << "Invalid register name in line " << line << std::endl;

    }
    return rs;
}

    std::vector<int> assembler::formati(std::string instr, lexer::token toke1, lexer::token toke2, lexer::token toke3, int line)
{
    int rt = 0, rs = 0, imm = 0;
    std::vector<int> x;
    opcode currop;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)ops.size(); i++)
    {
        if (instr == ops.at(i).instruct)
            currop = ops.at(i);
    }
    try
    {
        if (currop.isbranch)
        {
            if (toke1.type == lexer::token::Integer)
                throw 1;
            else
            {
                rt = findnum(toke1.string());
                if (rt == -1)
                    throw 2;
            }
            if (toke2.type == lexer::token::Integer)
                throw 1;
            else
            {
                rs = findnum(toke2.string());
                if (rs == -1)
                    throw 2;
            }
            if (toke3.type == lexer::token::Integer)
                imm = toke3.integer();
            else
                saverel(instr, toke3.string(), line, rt, rs);
        }
        else if (currop.isloadstore)
        {
            if ((instr == "lbu") || (instr == "sb"))
            {
                if (toke2.type == lexer::token::String)
                    throw 1;
                else
                {
                    if (toke2.integer() < 0)
                        imm = (0xFFFF << 16) + (0xFF << 8) + toke2.integer();
                    else
                        imm = toke2.integer();
                }
                if (toke1.type == lexer::token::Integer)
                    throw 1;
                else
                {
                    rt = findnum(toke1.string());
                    if (rt == -1)
                        throw 2;
                }
                if (toke3.type == lexer::token::Integer)
                    throw 1;
                else
                {
                    rs = findnum(toke2.string());
                    if (rs == -1)
                        throw 2;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (toke2.type == lexer::token::String)
                    throw 1;
                else
                {
                    if (toke2.integer() < 0)
                        imm = (0xFFFF << 16) + toke2.integer();
                    else
                        imm = toke2.integer();
                }
                if (toke1.type == lexer::token::Integer)
                    throw 1;
                else
                {
                    rt = findnum(toke1.string());
                    if (rt == -1)
                        throw 2;
                }
                if (toke3.type == lexer::token::Integer)
                    throw 1;
                else
                {
                    rs = findnum(toke2.string());
                    if (rs == -1)
                        throw 2;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ((instr == "andi") || (instr == "ori"))
            {
                if (toke1.type == lexer::token::Integer)
                    throw 1;
                else
                {
                    rt = findnum(toke1.string());
                    if (rt == -1)
                        throw 2;
                }
                if (toke2.type == lexer::token::Integer)
                    throw 1;
                else
                {
                    rs = findnum(toke2.string());
                    if (rs == -1)
                        throw 2;
                }
                if (toke3.type == lexer::token::Integer)
                    imm = toke3.integer();
                else
                    throw 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (toke1.type == lexer::token::Integer)
                    throw 1;
                else
                {
                    rt = findnum(toke1.string());
                    if (rt == -1)
                        throw 2;
                }
                if (toke2.type == lexer::token::Integer)
                    throw 1;
                else
                {
                    rs = findnum(toke2.string());
                    if (rs == -1)
                        throw 2;
                }
                if (toke3.type == lexer::token::Integer)
                {
                    if (toke3.integer() < 0)
                        imm = (0xFFFF << 16) + toke2.integer();
                    else
                        imm = toke3.integer();
                }
                else
                    throw 1;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        if (e == 1)
            std::cerr << "Wrong argument in line " << line << std::endl;
        else
            std::cerr << "Invalid register name in line " << line << std::endl;
    }
    x.push_back(rt);
    x.push_back(rs);
    x.push_back(imm);
    return x;
}

std::vector<int> assembler::formati(std::string instr, lexer::token toke1, lexer::token toke2, int line)
{
    int rt = 0, imm = 0;
    std::vector<int> rval;
    try
    {
        if (toke1.type == lexer::token::Integer)
            throw 1;
        else
        {
            rt = findnum(toke1.string());
            if (rt == -1)
                throw 2;
        }
        if (toke2.type == lexer::token::String)
            throw 1;
        else
            imm = toke2.integer();
    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        if (e == 1)
            std::cerr << "Wrong argument in line " << line << std::endl;
        else
            std::cerr << "Invalid register name in line " << line << std::endl;

    }
    rval.push_back(rt);
    rval.push_back(imm);
    return rval;
}

void assembler::add(std::string label, std::string instr, const std::vector<lexer::token> &token, int linen)
{
    int assembled = 0, rd = 0, rt = 0;
    std::vector<int> argh;
    int arg;
    if (label.length() > 0)
        savesymb(label, linen);
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)functions.size(); i++)
    {
        if (instr == functions.at(i).instruct)
            type = R;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)ops.size(); i++)
    {
        if (instr == ops.at(i).instruct)
            type = I;
    }
    if (type == R)
    {
        try
        {
            if (instr == "jr")
            {
                if ((int)token.size() == 1)
                {
                    arg = formatr(instr, token.at(0), linen);
                    assembled = rassemble(instr, rd, arg, rt, 0);
                }
                else
                    throw 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((int)token.size() == 3)
                {
                    argh = formatr(instr, token.at(0), token.at(2), token.at(3), linen);
                    assembled = rassemble(instr, argh[0], argh[1], argh[2], argh[3]);
                }
                else
                    throw 1;
            }
        }
        catch (int e)
        {
            if (e == 1)
                std::cerr << "Wrong number of arguments at line " << linen << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else if (type == I)
    {
        try
        {
            if (instr == "lui")
            {
                if ((int)token.size() == 2)
                {
                    argh = formati(instr, token.at(0), token.at(1), linen);
                    assembled = iassemble(instr, argh[0], 0, argh[1]);
                }
                else
                    throw 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((int)token.size() == 3)
                {
                    argh = formati(instr, token.at(0), token.at(1), token.at(2), linen);
                    assembled = iassemble(instr, argh[0], argh[1], argh[2]);
                }
                else
                    throw 1;
            }
        }
        catch (int e)
        {
            if (e == 1)
                std::cout << "Wrong number of arguments at line " << linen << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "Instruction not recognized at line " << linen << std::endl;
    results.push_back(assembled);
}

void assembler::secAdd(void)
{
    std::vector<int>::iterator iter = results.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)reloctable.size(); i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < symbtable.size(); j++)
        {
            if (reloctable.at(i).label == symbtable.at(j).label)
            {
                int assembled = 0;
                iter += (reloctable.at(i).rlinenum / 4);
                for (unsigned int k = 0; k < ops.size(); k++)
                {
                    if (reloctable.at(i).instruct == ops.at(k).instruct)
                        type = I;
                }
                if (type == I)
                    assembled = iassemble(reloctable.at(i).instruct, reloctable.at(i).rt, reloctable.at(i).rs, symbtable.at(i).slinenum);
                else
                    std::cerr << "Instruction not recognized at line " << reloctable.at(i).rlinenum << std::endl;
                results.erase(iter);
                results.insert(iter, assembled);
            }
        }
    }
}

int assembler::rassemble(std::string instr, int rd, int rs, int rt, int shamt)
{
    int func = 0;
    int code = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)functions.size(); i++)
    {
        if (instr == functions.at(i).instruct)
        {
            func = functions.at(i).funct;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (i == (functions.size() - 1))
                return -1;
        }
    }
    code = (rs << 21) + (rt << 16) + (rd << 11) + (shamt << 6) + func;
    return code;
}

int assembler::iassemble(std::string instr, int rt, int rs, int imm)
{
    int op = 0;
    int code = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)ops.size(); i++)
    {
        if (instr == ops.at(i).instruct)
        {
            op = ops.at(i).opc;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (i == (ops.size() - 1))
                return -1;
        }
    }
    code = (op << 26) + (rs << 21) + (rt << 16) + imm;
    return code;
}

void assembler::p()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)results.size(); i++)
        std::cout << results.at(i) << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

When debugging, the tokens parameter triggers the error, and the this pointer in the vector code shows that the vector size changes to 0 at these lines:

```
#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
        if (size() <= _Pos)
```

What exactly is happening?

Sorry if my formatting is bad/wrong, etc., and please let me know if I should make any edits/provide more code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see output from `std::cout << "label = " << lexed[i].labels[0] << "\n";` just before the error? Is it possible that `lexed[i].labels` is empty?

Comment: Yes, I did see output. The pointer this was not empty, but changes to empty between the lines `#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2 ` and
`if (size() <= _Pos)`

Comment: It is not about the pointer. The pointer points to `labels` object. However, that object may be empty. Check `myassembler.add(lexed[i].labels.empty() ? "" : lexed[i].labels[0], lexed[i].name, tokens, i);`

Comment: Oh, you're talking about the labels object! I forgot about that! Thanks, that might be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by accessing by index vector element that does not exist.
In you case `lexed[i]` should be valid. So, the only possible issue may be with empty `labels` vector. Validate this vector before accessing its elements, for example

```
myassembler.add(lexed[i].labels.empty() ? "" : lexed[i].labels[0],
    lexed[i].name, tokens, i);
```

Actually there is one more bug for very large `lexed` arrays when integer index may overflow. You should not cast result of `.size()` to `int`. Instead proper type should be used for `i`:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < lexed.size(); i++)
```